# Is there a way to host MATLAB web app (designed in App Designer) on Github Pages?

Tags: matlab, webserver, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have already created and designed my MATLAB app in App Designer, where it currently works fine with the executable deployment. However, I've been researching the implementation of my application into a web browser, and have attempted doing it through MATLAB Web App Server, however it only seems to work while I have the run button pressed, obviously. Additionally, I attempted to create an AWS server using the [MATLAB tutorial](https://github.com/mathworks-ref-arch/matlab-web-app-server-on-aws/blob/main/README.md#step-2-configure-the-stack), however for some reason my stack build always fails.

So just curious is there another way to do this, such that either the server can host my app indefinitely, or perhaps run it through a GitHub pages account because my current project is saved on Github?

Answer (score 0):

You need a back server which runs the MATLAB engine (or MCR).

Something you can not do on GitHub as they don't dedicate you a server for persistent work.